# Laravel set dynamic config variable for whole project

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I'm working on a CMS with Laravel to manage other databases. Now i use the config function to create a temporary config variable. I do this for the external database and it also works.

This is what my code looks like now:

```
$website = Website::where('hash', '=', $hash)->first();

config(['database.connections.extern.host' => $website->db_host]);
config(['database.connections.extern.database' => $website->db_name]);
config(['database.connections.extern.username' => $website->db_username]);
config(['database.connections.extern.password' => $website->db_password]);
```

The problem is now, wherever I want to call the external database, I should do this. That is of course not convenient.

Does anyone know a solution to this 'problem'?

Comment: Sure. Put a method on your Website class, something like `$website->loadDatabase()`, that does these config changes, and call that when you need it.

Comment: That would indeed be a better solution. The best thing would be if this can be done somewhere in a main file, that it is executed with every request. I have already tried a few things in the AppServiceProvider, but without result.

Comment: You could do this in a service provider - if you show us what you tried and what went wrong there, perhaps we can assist more. Be aware that the config cache may come into play, though.

Comment: My website class:

public static function loadDatabase()
    {
        $website = Website::where('id', '=', session('website_id'))->first();

        config(['database.connections.extern.host' => $website->db_host]);
        config(['database.connections.extern.database' => $website->db_name]);
        config(['database.connections.extern.username' => $website->db_username]);
        config(['database.connections.extern.password' => $website->db_password]);
    }

Comment: My AppServiceProvider:

public function boot()
    {

        if (session('website_id')) {

            Website::loadDatabase();
        }
    }

Comment: Butt got this error:

`SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: SHOW TABLES)`

Comment: You should `dd(config('database.connections.extern'))` and make sure the values are what you think they are.

Comment: I tried it with a hard-coded ID instead of one from the session. That works, so the problem is variable in that session. And that is filled if I dd () in a blade.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through Website model and set config file at the startup and use website's hash as the key:

```
foreach (Website::all() as $website) {
    config(['database.connections.'.$website->hash.'.host' => $website->db_host]);
    ...
}
```

And then use website hash to connect to relevant DB:

```
DB::connection($hash) ...
```

Anyway this is not a good way to manage other databases if they are on different hosts. You better use web services technique to do such work. Connecting to external DB is potentially insecure.